# Symfony UniqueEntity validation issue

Tags: php, symfony, validation

I tried to use UniqueEntity constraint on a simple entity. The problem is, i'm redirect on error page and i don't have any error message below my field.

Here is my entity :

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntity;

/**
 * Plant
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="plant")
 * @UniqueEntity(fields="name", message="Champ unique")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="MyBundle\Repository\PlantRepository")
*/
class Plant
{
/**
 * @var int
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=255, unique=true)
 */
private $name;

/**
 * @var \Boolean
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="upstream", type="boolean", nullable=true)
 */
private $upstream;

/**
 * @var \Boolean
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="downstream", type="boolean", nullable=true)
 */
private $downstream;

// Some getters / setters
```

I followed the documentation : set attribute to `unique=true`, set the uniqueEntity to the class and add `use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntity;`

And i have always this error on the error page :

```
An exception occurred while executing 'INSERT INTO plant (name, upstream, downstream) VALUES (?, ?, ?)' with params ["XXXX", 0, 1]:

SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry 'XXXX' for key 'UNIQ_AB030D725E237E06'
```

I was searching for solution on other topic but nothing works and i don't understand where is/are the mistake.

Someone know how to handle this ?

Answer (score 1):

I hesitated to delete my question because the answer is a little bit silly. But I hope it can be useful for someone.

It couldn't work because in the controller, I forgot to use:

```
$form->isValid()
```

So now in the controller I added it:

```
$request->isMethod('POST') && $form->handleRequest($request)->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()
```

And now all works fine. I am getting the error message below the form field.